# Windows Explorer in Qt Application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, activex

I would like to embed a Windows Explorer (not internet explorer) in my Qt application so that the user has a view to a Windows directory and can do regular file operations such as double-click to open, or rename. I understand that ActiveX is the way to re-use this sort of objects on Windows.

Is this possible and what is the suggested way of achieving this?

Thank you.

Comment: there's an [Active Qt module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/activeqt/activeqt-index.html) available to use ActiveX widgets

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing an [`IShellView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a QFilesystemModel to obtain the file and directory listing, then use a QTreeView to display it.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-dirview-main-cpp.html

Comment: Unfortunately QTreeView would have built-in support Windows Explorer context menus such as Tortoise SVN etc. I assume that would require manual replication of the context menu (hence will be error prone).